# Laravel 5 pivot table update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have many to many relationship between podkategorija and artikal tables and pivot table artikal_podkategorija. Inserting works fine but i don't have idea how to update data in pivot table. I trying to update artikal data and to update pivot table data artikal_id which is selected from selectform.

PIVOT TABLE

```
Schema::create('artikal_podkategorija', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('artikal_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('artikal_id')->references('id')->on('artikli')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('podkategorija_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('podkategorija_id')->references('id')->on('podkategorije')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Edit view

```
    {!! Form::model($artikal, ['method' => 'PATCH' , 'action' => ['ArtikliController@update', $artikal->id]]) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Podkategorija', 'Podkategorija:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('podkategorija_id[]', $podkategorija, null, array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Podkategorija',)) !!}


    {!! Form::label('Naziv', 'Naziv artikla:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('Naziv', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Izmijeni podkategoriju', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
</div>


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

My Controller

```
public function store(CreateArtikalRequest $request)
{

    $article = Artikal::create($request->all());
    $article->podkategorije()->attach($request->input('podkategorija'));


    return redirect('artikli');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is `updateExistingPivot()`, as described in the documentation : http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.1 or higher it should be something like this:

In your ArtikalsController:

```
public function edit($artikal_id)
{
   $artikal = Artikal::findOrFail($artikal_id);

   $podkategorijas = Podkategorija::lists('podkategorija_id', 'podkategorija_id');

   return view('artikals.edit', compact('artikal', 'podkategorijas'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $artikal_id)
{
    $artikal = Artikal::findOrFail($artikal_id);
    $artikal->update($request->all());

    $artikal->podkategorijas()->sync($request->input('podkategorijas_list'));

    return redirect('artikals');
}
```

In your Artikal model:

```
public function getPodkategorijaListAttribute()
{
   return $this->podkategorijas->lists('podkategorija_id')->all();
}
```

In your edit.blade.php:

```
{!! Form::label('podkategorija_list', 'Tags') !!}
{!! Form::select('podkategorija_list[]', $podkategorijas, null, ['multiple']) !!}
```